# ModelState.IsValid validation using ajax and json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code snippets.  Ultimately I'm trying to get the ModelState to show valid=false.  Right now it is saying valid=true.

**Ajax code:**

```
        $(':input', '#intform').each(function () {
            frmData[this.id] = this.value;
        });

        var DTO = { 'frmData': frmData };

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO)
        })
```

**webAPI controller:**

```
 public Object Post([FromBody]JObject data)
        dynamic json = data;
        frmData item = new frmData()
        {
             Subject = "Loan Request Received", 
             Body = "The following loan request has been received:",
             BName = json.frmData.BName,
             BType = json.frmData.BType,
             ...
        }
```

**Model:**

```
public class frmData
{
    [LookupValueValidation(maxLength = 50, required = true)]
    public string BName  
    {
        get { return _bName; }
        set { _bName = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value,true); }
    }
}
```

**I'd like to use this construct in the webApi Controller:**

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || data == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
```

However, if I type in 100 characters for BName the ModelState says that it is valid = true.  I would expect it to be false.  I have a feeling there is a disconnect between how I am getting the data as a JSON object, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Why is your controller method not accepting the class `frmData` as a parameter instead of `JObject`?  The `Model` that you are passing through to the controller is a `JObject` not your own model with the validation.

Comment: Currently when you create `frmData` manually, it can't affect `ModelState` in any way.

Comment: so the way I did it, there is NO WAY to do server side model validation?

Comment: I think you can use [Validator.TryValidateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate it server-side; although, as others have said, I don't believe you can change the `ModelState` value.

Comment: @Stryner - if you add this as an answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stryner mentioned the `Validator.TryValidateObject` worked for me:

```
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(item, new ValidationContext(item, null, null), errors, true);
```

I set up a `ValidationResult` List to capture any errors:

```
var errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
```

I was able to loop through any errors using this construct:

```
foreach(ValidationResult vr in errors){
    vrMessage.Add(vr.ErrorMessage.ToString());
    return Json(new { fail = vr.ErrorMessage.ToString() });
}
```

The `ValidationResult` loop is kind of hokey and probably would need to be modified, but I  only need to return the first error for this application so I left it in its current state.